# How can I play audio elements in sync with key presses?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, key-events

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="words" name="words"></textarea>
<audio id="type" src="type.mp3"></audio>
```

**JS**

```
document.getElementById('words').onkeydown = function(){
    document.getElementById('type').play();
}
```

I want to make type.mp3 to play anytime I press any key.

But, it is not played in sync with the key.

I am looking for a pure JS solution.

Comment: You are assuming we know/understand what the problem is. What do you mean by *"played synchronously"*?

Comment: @charlietfl when i type sequentially, the audio is not played until previous one is ended.

Comment: Would need to keep track of key event counts and use the audio ended event to play itself again if counter not zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The audio media element depends on the buffering mechanism of the browser and may not play instantly when play is called.

To play sounds in sync with key-presses you would have to use the Web Audio API instead which allows you to play a in-memory buffer and therefor instantly.

**Here is an example of how you can load and trigger the sound:**

```js
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

var request = new XMLHttpRequest(),
    url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/8fp1hnkwp215gfs/chirp.wav",
    actx = new AudioContext(),
    abuffer;

// load file via XHR
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
request.onload = function() {
  // Asynchronously decode the audio file data in request.response
  actx.decodeAudioData(request.response,
    function(buffer) {
      if (buffer) {
        abuffer = buffer; // keep a reference to decoded buffer
        setup();          // setup handler
      }
    }
  )
};
request.send();

  // setup key handler
function setup() {
  document.getElementById("txt").onkeydown = play;
}

  // play sample - a new buffer source must be created each time
function play() {
  var src = actx.createBufferSource();
  src.buffer = abuffer;
  src.connect(actx.destination);
  src.start(0);
}
```

```html
<textarea id=txt></textarea>
```

(note: there seem to be a bug in Firefox at the time of this writing reporting a column which does not exist in the code at the send() call - if a problem, try the code in Chrome).

Comment: (the bug seem to only be related to Firefox v. 47.0b9 and should be considered temporary. Works in 48.0a2 and likely in the stable release).

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is an asynchronous and event-driven language, so you can't make a synchronous function.